# Check if a field is "undefined"

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I am using parse.com with Unity and c# and are having some problems checking if a field is empty ("undefined"). Is it possible to do so, and if yes... How? The reason for this is that I have added an column to an class, and by default it makes the fields undefined.

I have tried this but with no luck:

```
if(myObject.get<int>("myfield") == null)
```

And this:

```
if(myObject.get<int>("myfield") == "undefined")
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you tried debugging and adding a watch to myObject.get<int>("myfield")? I think its value is 0 since it's an int

Comment: Crazy, not one reference to potentially null values or missing columns in their documentation for the API. I would surmise you want to look for the existence of the column on `myObject` via an indexer, like `myObject["myfield"] == null` or something, perhaps the value is also `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing some information here. First of all you're calling `.get` which signifies that you're using the javascript version of unity.com sdk. But you're also using `.get<T>` which signifies that you're using the C# version of unity.com sdk, so which is it?

On another note, what is actually the problem? Does your `.Get<int>("myfield")` crash or does it yield -1, or 0?

Maybe try returning int as a nullable and then checking if it has a value: `if (myObject.Get<int?>("myfield").HasValue)`

Comment: Hi, I am using unity c# and when trying to call the column I get this: The given key was not present in the dictionary.?

Comment: Ah, you want to check if the column/property exists, not wether or not it has a value assigned to it. Check if there are any methods on your object that you could use in order to check if a field exists with that name, for example: .HasKey("myfield") or .Fields.Contains("myfield")

Comment: PERFECT :-) I wrote this and it works: MyObject.ContainsKey("myfield") - Thanks... You just made my day :-)